# How to disable wifi while running Migration Assistant?

Tags: wifi, migration, migration-assistant

After starting to run Migration Assistant over wifi, I connected an Ethernet cable to both machines in order to speed up the transfer. This does not appear to be working. How can I disable wifi on one or both machines? The normal menu system does not appear to be accessible. Both machines are running updated versions of Mavericks.

Comment: you can not switch services middle in the process. End the migration then switch

Comment: How do I end the migration without waiting for it to finish?